# Wiring a component with typed Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a component - 'App.tsx' that has a type definition for its props. The props include an array of todos and an action creator that will be injected by connect (react-redux). However I cannot wire the component 'App' in say 'index.tsx' without passing these required props. Is there an alternative to specifying these props as optional in the interface? If they are optional then I have to do null checks everywhere I access them.

I read through using redux with typescript among other documentation but found no answers.

index.tsx =>

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The above code has errors because App component below expects the two params - 'todos' and 'fetchTodos'

App.tsx =>

```
interface AppProps {
    todos: Todo[];
    fetchTodos(): any;
}

class _App extends Component<AppProps> {

    onButtonClick = (): void => {
        this.props.fetchTodos();
    }
    renderList(): JSX.Element[] | undefined {
        return this.props.todos.map((todo: Todo) => {
            return (
                <div key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</div>
            );
        });
    }
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <>
                <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Fetch</button>
                {this.renderList()}
            </>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ todos }: StoreState, ownProps: AppProps): { todos: Todo[]; } => {
    return {
        todos
    };
};

export const App = connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchTodos })(_App);
```

I would like to see if there is a way to not specify the two props as optional in the AppProps interface because they would absolutely be injected by connect.

Answer (score 0):

Just as any other `TypeScript` interface (or function parameters or class memembers), you can declare optional types using the `?` flag:

```
interface AppProps {
    todos?: Todo[];
    fetchTodos()?: any;
}
```

You can read more about optional parameters and members in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties).

**Later edit:**
So you want the mapped props to be excluded?

Usually I declare my prop types as this, I created two prop interfaces (one for mapped props and one for props that I expected to be passed):

```
interface IOwnProps {
    fetchTodos(): any;
}

interface IPropsFromState {
    todos: Todo[];
}

type IProps = IOwnProps & IPropsFromState;

const mapStateToProps = (state: IRootState): IPropsFromState ({
   todos: state.todos  
});

class _App extends Component<IProps> {
 ...
}

export const App = connect(mapStateToProps)(_App);
```

Comment: It looks like my question wasn’t clear. I am trying to find a way to not set these as optional in the AppProps interface so that I don’t have to do null checks everywhere AND not pass values for these injected props when I wire App index.tsx

Comment: @cubsnlinux If you don't add the question mark they will be required. Make sure you are using a recent version of TypeScript and that strict mode is enabled. Or you want them to both be `required` and not pass them? That makes them optional and you would need null checks.

Comment: See my edit, maybe that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @Cristy. I solved it in a different way (See my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how connect jugles the types.

Connect is the best explained when looking from the right to the left:

Your component accepts 2 props: `todos`, `fetchTodos`.

Then it looks at the `mapDispatchToProps`. Your implentation of this provides `fetchTodos`. The new prop list is: `todos`

It finally looks at `mapStateToProps`: it provides `todos`, but to execute the function, it requires an object containi g: `todos`, `fetchTodos`

Your final component contains these props: `todos`, `fetchTodos`

This is not what you want, you want none props.

You need to adjust your `mapStateToProps` function:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ todos }: StoreState, ownProps: {}): { todos: Todo[]; } => { return { todos };
```

Or simply:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ todos }: StoreState): { todos: Todo[]; } => { return { todos };
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I solved the above:

```
interface ReduxInjectedProps{
   fetchTodos:typeof fetchTodos;
   todos:Todo[];
}  

class _App extends Component {
    get injected(){
       return this.props as ReduxInjectedProps;
    }
    onButtonClick = (): void => {
        this.injected.fetchTodos();
    }
    renderList(): JSX.Element[] | undefined {
        return this.injected.todos.map((todo: Todo) => {
            return (
                <div key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</div>
            );
        });
    }
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <>
                <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Fetch</button>
                {this.renderList()}
            </>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ todos }: StoreState, ownProps: AppProps): { todos: Todo[]; } => {
    return {
        todos
    };
};

export const App = connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchTodos })(_App);
```